# OS X back/forward gestures in Eclipse IDE

Tags: eclipse, macos, eclipse-plugin, osx-yosemite

is there any plugin or possibility to use back/forward gestures in Eclipse IDE on OS X (like in Safari or Chrome) to open back/forward edit location? I tried to use [BetterTouchTool](http://www.bettertouchtool.net/), but it does not work with eclipse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works with BetterTouchTool, I forgot to restart Eclipse IDE.